# APNSに関するリジェクトの回避方法

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, push-notification

APNSを利用したアプリをAppleに審査請求したところ、リジェクトされました。
その回避方法がわからないため教えてください。

■開発したアプリについて
・Xcode v6.3.1(SDK8.3)
・開発言語 objective-c
・iPhone用(iOS7.1以上)
・AWSSNS利用

リジェクト時のAppleからのコメントは次の通りです。

> 5.3 - Apps that send Push Notifications without first obtaining user consent, as well as apps that require Push Notifications to function, will be rejected
>   5.3 Details
>   We noticed that your app requires Push Notifications in order to function. 
>   Specifically, your app requires to opt-in to Push Notifications in order to access the app.

私は「Push通知の送信許可をアプリのユーザに促してね」ということだと解釈しています。

開発したアプリは初回起動時にユーザにPush通知送信の許可を問うダイアログが表示されるように実装しており、少なくとも実デバイスを使ったテスト環境ではダイアログが表示されます。

具体的には、AppDelegate.mのapplication:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:に以下のコードを書いています。

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }
    else {
        //iOS7
        UIRemoteNotificationType types =UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert| UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:types];
    }
```

他に設定が必要なのでしょうか。
リジェクトを回避したくよろしく願いします。

Comment: 5.3のDetailsでは、「Pushを有効にしないとアプリを利用できないように見えるだけど？」と読めますが、実際そうなっていますか？（Push無効でもアプリが使えることを説明する必要がありそう）

Comment: @fkmさん、開発したアプリはPushが必須機能で、Push無効であればメイン機能を実現できません。無効であれば使えないように実装してありますが、リジェクトされたということは、それがiOSアプリの規約違反ということですね(アプリの必須機能としてPushを使用できない)。理由がわかり、とても助かりました。ありがとうございました。